# Use groupby with inner join to get unique record on single column

Tags: sql-server

I need unique record on colum a.[id] so I am using group but it getting error

```
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'dbo.assessment_dfn.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

### Query

```
SELECT a.[id] AS AssessmentID
  --,ad.[code] AS Assessment_Dfn_Code
  ,ad.[name] AS Assessment_Dfn_name
  ,mdfn.[id] AS Module_Dfn_ID
  ,a.[student_stage]
  ,a.[assessments_sitting]
  ,a.[sitting_date]
  ,ads.[sitting_number]
  ,s.[id] AS StudentID
  ,a.[assessor] AS AssessorID
  ,mdfn.[lead] AS ModuleLead
  ,a.[submission_date]
  ,a.[status]
  ,a.[complete]
  ,a.[assessment]
  ,a.[saved]
  ,ele_cliPro.[grade] AS GradeID
  ,codGrd.[name] AS GradeName


FROM [adb_TestDb].[dbo].[assessments] AS a (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [adb_TestDb].[dbo].[student_stage] AS ss ON a.[student_stage] = ss.[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[assessment_dfn_sittings] ads WITH (NOLOCK) ON ads.[id] = a.[assessments_sitting]
INNER JOIN [adb_TestDb].[dbo].[students] AS s ON ss.student = s.[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[assessment_dfn] ad WITH (NOLOCK) ON ad.[id] = ads.[assessment]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[module_dfn] AS mdfn ON ad.[module] = mdfn.[id]
INNER JOIN [adb_TestDb].[dbo].[elements_clinicalprocedures] AS ele_cliPro ON a.[id] = ele_cliPro.[assessment] 
INNER JOIN [adb_TestDb].[dbo].[codes_grade_details] AS codGrd ON ele_cliPro.[grade] = codGrd.[id] AND codGrd.[id] = 4
where a.id= 2532
group by  a.[id]
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by SQL you cannot get columns when using GROUP BY if they are not in that clause or in an aggregate function.
If you need only one record and you know all values are the same you could try to use an aggregate function for all the values required (eg MAX) but this solution should be used only if you are completely aware of getting only one among the possible values!

Comment: what I have multiple instance of assessment IDs above which is correct but I want to get only single instance of same  assessment ID record

Comment: could you provide some data and then the required data set, it would be easier

Comment: Excuse me but it is not clear to me what you're trying to say: if you comment the GROUP BY how many rows are you getting? if you change SELECT to SELECT DISTINCT are those rows the same number? I'm trying to understand which is your needing ...